# Get the what() message of boost::exception

Tags: c++, boost

In the following code, I want to get the `what()` message of a boost::exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        int i(boost::lexical_cast<int>("42X"));
    }
    catch (boost::exception const &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << boost::diagnostic_information_what(e) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the message :

```
Exception: Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >
```

But when I do not catch the exception, the shell outputs :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
[1]    8744 abort      ./a.out
```

I want that message : `bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target`; but I could not find the way to have it. The boost exception system is a mystery to me.

How to get this very message ?

Edit: **boost::exception has no `what()` method.** So, how the shell can it write `std::exception::what: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target`, since this is not an `std::exception` ?

Comment: since the advent of c++11's nested exceptions I can't find a strong case for using boost::exception. is it too late to do it the standard way? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch it as `bad_lexical_cast` to use the method `what()`:

```
catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
{      //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
                              //  ^^^^^^^^
}
```

And it will display `Exception: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target`

Comment: Thank you very much. How is it possible the base class does not contain a pure virtual method `what()` ? Why such a choice ?

Comment: it inherits the `what()` from `std::bad_cast` as seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#bad_lexical_cas), which inherits from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast)

Comment: It is weird. I supposed every exception from boost derived from the only `boost::exception`, like `std::exception`.

Comment: `boost::exception` is not equivalent to `std::exception`. It provides different functionality and in most cases exceptions thrown by Boost libraries derive from both. In your code you rarely need to catch `boost::exception` and usually want to catch either `std::exception` or whatever the final exception type that is expected to be thrown by the library.

Answer (score 4):

From [the `diagnostic_information_what` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/exception/doc/diagnostic_information_what.html):

> The diagnostic_information_what function is intended to be called from a user-defined std::exception::what() override.

The function is not supposed to give you the message from the `what()` function, it's supposed to be used *in* the `what()` function to create a message to return.

Then to continue, from [the `boost::lexical_cast` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast):

> If the conversion is unsuccessful, a bad_lexical_cast exception is thrown.

So lets take a look the [`bad_lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.bad_lexical_cast):

> ```
> class bad_lexical_cast : public std::bad_cast
> ```

It inherits from the *standard* [`std::bad_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) which inherits from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) which have a `what()` member function.

So the solution is to catch `boost::bad_lexical_cast` (or `std::exception`) instead of `boost::exception` which is not involved at all.